# What is the correct and most memory efficient way to send notifications while in background?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm building a chat app and I noticed that when I wanted to build notifications, I saw that Slack doesn't use a `Service` to push notifications while in the background.

I was just curious if it's possible to push notifications without using a `Service` and if it's more efficient or less time consuming than using a `Service`.

Comment: How are you determining this?  They may use an IntentService which is a Service that automatically shuts down when the work is done.

Comment: I just noticed that it didn't show up as a running app, and it didn't show up in Process Stats in the Background section. I assumed they were using a different method to push notifications.

Comment: Premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to send a notification when something happens, like a chat message is received? If so, and if that event sends a system-wide broadcast, then you should register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for it and build your notification whenever it sees the event is broadcast. You can also schedule timed notifications this way.